# C# check value of object from user input

Tags: c#, class, object

I am writing a spot of code for keeping track of a shared bank account for a school class. I have made each student an object based on the following:

```
        public string name;
        private int totalAmount;
        private int debt;


        public Student(string aName, int aTotalAmount, int 
        aDebt)
        {
            name = aName;
            totalAmount = aTotalAmount;
            debt = aDebt;
        }

        public int TotalAmount
        {
            get { return totalAmount; }

        }
        public int Debt
        {
            get { return debt; }
        }
```

I want the user to write the name of a student and have it reply with the amount of money they have paid (totalAmount) and the amount of debt they are in (debt). How would I do this?

A student, for reference:

```
Student Sander = new Student("Sander", 0, 120);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could put your student objects in a dictionary and use the name as the key. Then when you want to get one Student, you just have to get to value thanks to his key.

```
Student student = myDictionary["Sander"];
```

By doing this, you couldn't have several students with the same name.

Comment: That certainly sounds like a solution. Haven't used dictionaries before, I'll check it out.

Comment: Using the name as a key is not a good idea as the author suggests - you can't have duplicate names. I'd recommend introducing an `Id` field which should be unique for each `Student` and use it as a dictionary key instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection student then you can use Linq for get necessary information.

```
List<Student> students = GetStudents(); // from database
string inputValue = input.Text; //your input value
Student currentStudent = students.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Contains(inputValue)); // your object which have all information what you need
```

If object won't be find, this method return null. So won't forgot check currentStudent on null.

Good luck!